# How do I properly style a button in WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I know this is a basic question, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to do this properly.

Given the following XAML:

```
<Button>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="16" Height="16" Source="Resources/accept.png" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">Continue</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

How would I convert that to a style so that it can be easily reused? What if I were to want to supply the image source and text in an attribute? Is that possible?

On a related note, what are the best practices for structuring the files where you store your styles, etc? Do you just drop them into a new XAML file and stick them in a styles solution folder?

I'm very new to WPF, so, again, I apologize for the basic question.

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 1:**

There are a couple of ways to style controls. You can access them as a `StaticResource`, or supply a `TargetType` so all the styles get applied to the Controls of that type.

To parameterize your style you could consider DataBinding. If for instance you have a model that supplies content for these buttons you could try something like:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Path=Image}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=Text}" />
                </Grid>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>

<Button x:Name="myButton1"  Width="100" Height="100" />
```

This would be an example of how to set the content.

```
myButton1.DataContext = new ButtonCaption {Text = "Testing"};

public class ButtonCaption
{
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where abouts in my solution should I place the style? In the XAML of that's going to use it or in new XAML? And, last but not least, what about supplying the parameters in an attribute on Button.. Is that possible?

Comment: You can also have the style automatically applied to all buttons in the scope by removing the `x:Key` attribute and just leaving `TargetType`.

Comment: Thanks -- I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Can I supply the content using a pure XAML approach (or do I need to do binding in C#?)

Answer (score 1):

what you really want is a control template, not just a simple style.  [Here](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html) is a pretty decent tutorial on the whole thing.

Comment: He's only changing the content of the Button. ControlTemplating would also change its appearance and behaviour.

Comment: you don't HAVE to change the appearance/behavior.  a control template would allow him to change the image and text of the button and be a better generalized solution. we are not talking about making a whole new control--which is also a possibility.